# Using move constructor as substitute for default constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

### The Question

I have a type `T` that is move assignable and move constructible but **not default constructible**. I want to create a `T temp[N];` using the move constructor so that I can safely move assign `T`s into `temp`.

I am most interested in the case where `temp` is a class member, but it may be easier to find a solution when `temp` is a local variable of a function. How can I do that?

### Background

I am writing a generic library function that will execute many `std::swap`s:

```
template<typename T>
void func(){
    
    while(true){
        // do stuff

        // perform swap
        std::swap(t1, t2);
    }

}
```

A typical implementation of `std::swap` is the following:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& t1, T& t2) {
    T temp = std::move(t1); // or T temp(std::move(t1));
    t1 = std::move(t2);
    t2 = std::move(temp);
}
```

Every invocation of `std::swap` will allocate a `T temp` and call `T temp`s destructor. I want to eliminate this cost.

If the `T` is default constructible, I may try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void func(){

    T temp;
    
    while(true){
        // do stuff

        // perform swap
        temp = std::move(t1);
        t1 = std::move(t2);
        t2 = std::move(temp);
    }
}
```

**In my case, I cannot assume `T` is default constructible, but I may assume it is move assignable and move constructible.** If I happen to have a `t` prior to the `while` loop, I can do the following:

```
template<typename T>
void func(){
    T temp = std::move(t);
    t = std::move(temp);
    while(true){
        // do stuff

        // perform swap
        t = std::move(t1);
        t1 = std::move(t2);
        t2 = std::move(t);
    }
}
```

The above code works. However, there is a second optimization I haven't mentioned. After I swap `t1` and `t2`, it is likely that I will soon swap `t2` and `t3`. Instead of performing `t2 = std::move(t);` followed by `temp = std::move(t2);`, I want to leave the value of `t2` in `temp`.

At any given moment, there may be at most 8 `temp` values that have yet to be swapped to their final destination (well, not 8, but a large `constexpr` number determined by the library user). If `T` were default constructible, that would look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void func(){
    T temp[8];

    while(true){
        // do stuff

        // perform swap
        t1 = std::move(temp[i]);
        temp[i] = std::move(t2);
    }
}
```

which doesn't work since `T temp[8];` calls `T`s default constructor. My idea now looks something like this

1. Allocate some local uninitialized memory for a `T temp[8];` with something like `malloc`.
2. Move-construct the first 8 `temp`s into the uninitialized memory with placement `new`.
3. Somehow ensure destructors are called for the moved-out-of `temp`s.

Comment: If you plan to replace the array with automatic storage duration with dynamic allocation you might as well use `std::vector` instead

Comment: Don't call placement-new manually. Use (an array of) `std::optional` to hold those temporary values.

Comment: If we ignore the chained swaps problem, I would say that it's up to `T` to overload `swap()` for itself, if the standard implementation is too expensive for it. You'd then do `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` to swap the object, which will pick up the custom overload, or fall back to `std::swap` if there's none.

Comment: @UnholySheep I want automatic storage for sure. I'm pretty sure I can see how it would be done with ```std::vector```.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat One reason that I don't like ```std::optional``` (besides the additional cost) is the design reason that I know now exactly when ```T temp[N];``` holds a valid value. After the first ```N``` values are entered, the temporary values will be valid until the end of the ```while``` loop, at which time the ```N``` values will be moved out before destruction. ```std::optional``` appears to me to solve a run-time issue.

Comment: If you really want to deal with the raw memory yourself then you probably want to have a buffer like `alignas(alignof(T)) buffer[sizeof(T) * N];` and for convenience a `T* temp = reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer);`. And then you have to deal with the move construction and destruction manually (probably using `std::uninitialized_move` and `std::destroy_at`)

Comment: @mbang Yep, `std::optional` might be redundant, but it's surely a lot safer. If you're sure it doesn't give you the performance you need, then sure, you can manage the lifetime manually.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads? If not, a function-local `static T` might help you out...